# Variational autoencoder (VAE) - decoder weights in Keras: access and interpretation

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I have 2 questions about the following VAE :

```
inputs = Input(shape=(input_size,), name='concat_input')
x = Dense(denselayer_size, activation=activ_fct, name="encoding")(inputs)
x = BN()(x)      # batch normalization
z_mean = Dense(latent_dims, name='z_mean')(x)
z_log_sigma = Dense(latent_dims, name='z_log_sigma', kernel_initializer='zeros')(x)
z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dims,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_sigma])
encoder = Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_sigma, z], name='encoder')
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dims,), name='z_sampling')
x = latent_inputs
x = Dense(denselayer_size, activation=activ_fct, name="decoding")(x)
x = BN()(x)
x=Dropout(dropout_ratio)(x)
out_layer = Dense(input_size, name="out")
concat_out = out_layer(x)
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, concat_out, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()
outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
vae = Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae_mlp')
```

1. After fitting the model, why can I access encoder weights with the following commands

   ```
    encoder_weights = vae.get_layer('encoder').get_layer('encoding').get_weights()[0]
    encoder_weights2 = vae.get_layer('encoding').get_weights()[0]
    np.all(np.equal(encoder_weights, encoder_weights2))
    # True
   ```

but the ones of the decoder only with

```
decoder_weights = vae.get_layer('decoder').get_layer('out').get_weights()[0]
# decoder_weights = vae.get_layer('out').get_weights()[0]  not working  !!! ERROR:
```

2. Besides, should the decoder and the encoder weights be interpreted differently ? I read in an article that says:

> Decoder weights captured the contribution of specific [input features]
> to each learned feature  ----  (Way and Greene 2018).

Intuitively, I would have thought that it would be the encoder weights that do so. What would be your interpretation of encoder, resp. decoder, weights ?